# Authorize users with different roles with user name in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is my code:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin", Users = "user1, user2")]       
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

I am trying to authorize users with admin role can access index method, as well as two additional users user1 and user2 to access it that are having different roles other than admin.

Above code is not working and redirecting to login, it is not allowing admin role uses to access index as well as two additional users - user1 and user2 that are having different role are not able to access it

Comment: And what's the question pls?

Comment: And the problem is.....?

Comment: the given code is not working, it is not allowing admin role uses to access index as well as two additional users - user1 and user2 that are having different role are not able to access it.

Comment: So what authentication / authorization system are you using?  SimpleMembershipProvider or Asp.Net Identity or Integrated?  How's it been configured up - where's the code?